# Draw lines between coordinates of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, coordinates

I would like to draw lines between the coordinates of the matrix below and then plot it, it should become an F.

```
F = ([0 2 2 7 7 2 2 8 8 0 0;0 0 8 8 10 10 14 14 16 16 0])
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How are the lines defined?

Comment: Do you want to connect the coordinates?

Comment: @herohuyongtao The first coordinates are (0,0)(2,0)(2,8)(7,8)(7,10)... and so on.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to do this with

```
 plot(F(1,:),F(2,:))
```

the style that you are plotting the data with has many options that you can refer to here http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
plot(F(1,:),F(2,:),'k-.')
```

I dont have matlab here, but this must work!